# Flutter Flame Background image full screen

Tags: flutter, windows, flame

I'm using the Tick Tack Toe app sample and modified the Play session screen to use a Flame Game widget.  I'm trying to set a full screen background image (windows) that will resize when the window resizes.  The code below works great if I remove the Game widget and replace with a Container but when using the Game widget the background will not resize.  Is there a better way of doing this?

```
 return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/background1.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        // Replace the GameScreen with Container and it works as desired
        child: GameScreen(level)));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code, hope it helps:

```
class Background extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef<FlappyBirdGame> {
  Background();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final background = await Flame.images.load("Insert your background here");
    size = gameRef.size;
    sprite = Sprite(background);
  }
}
```

Here is "YourGame" class:

```
class YourGame extends FlameGame with TapDetector, HasCollisionDetection {
  YourGame();

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    addAll([
      Background(),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void onTap() {
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
  }
}
```

And in main.dart file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Flame.device.fullScreen();
  final game = YourGame();
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: game,
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code helped me find the issue.  The sizing of the background image was being sized to match the game size I set using camera component withFixedResolution which is not what I needed.  I wanted the physical  monitor size.  So I ended up modifying to pass in the flutter screen width and height from MediaQuery into Flame and then set the image size to that.  It works like a charm.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same full screen background throughout your game, you can try to set the background image inside the backgroundBuilder.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Flame.device.fullScreen();

  final game = YourGame();

  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: game,
      // Set full screen background.
      backgroundBuilder: (context) => Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("Insert your background here"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

It will resized accordingly to your windows screen. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great code. I'm sure I can use this down the road.  However, I want to change the background based on current game level.  Also, I would like to use the Tiled editor for background so I can line up game components/objects with the image elements i.e: platforms.